# Remove object from NSMutable array wont work

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutable array which i'm trying to remove objects from and by that to decrease

the count of number of objects on the array, and the count always stays the same,

Meaning, the remove is not working.

Here is the code (it's from the online stanford IOS development course):

```
- (NSMutableArray *)cards
{
    if (!_cards) _cards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return _cards;
}

- (void)addCard:(Card *)card atTop:(BOOL)atTop
{
    if (atTop) {
        [self.cards insertObject:card atIndex:0];
    } else {
        [self.cards addObject:card];
    }
}

- (void)addCard:(Card *)card
{
    [self addCard:card atTop:NO];
}

- (Card *)drawRandomCard
{
    Card* randomCard = Nil;
    NSLog(@"This is the count %d",[self.cards count]);
    if ([self.cards count]) {
        unsigned index = arc4random() % [self.cards count];
        randomCard = self.cards[index];
        [self.cards removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    }
    return randomCard;
}
```

The count is always 52, even after removing the objects.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What do you see if you also log the count immediately after calling `removeObjectAtIndex:`?  You might also try logging the value of `self.cards` (%p shows the address) at the start of `drawRandomCard` to see if the array is getting replaced somehow.

Comment: @PhillipMills well this is weird, but it is 51 after each random card drawing. why is that? and how could it be fixed?

Comment: You are removing 1 card each time of `drawingRandomCard` so I guess if you call the method once, then having a count of 51 is just what it should be

Comment: Is `addCard:` getting invoked after calling `drawRandomCard`, thus making count 52 again? Add a breakpoint in `addCard:` and see if it is getting called.

Comment: There are various possibilities...I suggest a log statement like `NSLog(@"Self %@, Array %p", self, self.cards);` when you enter the method and it may give a clue.

Comment: I think explaining more what you want to achieve with this operations and the code where you invoke these methods will help

Comment: @Amar you are right. add card indeed is called after. its a bit weird for me to debug on xcode, but thanks anyway! :)